# How to intercept Docker's container traffic with Burp?

Tags: docker, proxy, owasp, burp

I did the following:

```
Run docker pull bkimminich/juice-shop
Run docker run --rm -p 3000:3000 bkimminich/juice-shop
```

Browse to http://localhost:3000 with Burp listening to 127.0.0.1:8080 => I see external traffic (google, cdn...) but not internal (Docker container).

So please how to configure my container to connect it with my proxy Burp. Burp is installed on Windows not inside the container. Thks

Comment: The solution is to replace localhost with IP

Answer (score 0):

- While running Docker Pull, did you try to run it with 8080 port.

- If the problem is not resolved, try to open port 3000 from Burp Suite / Proxy / Settings.

- If there is a certificate setting in the Docker container, I suggest you check it.